# Usar métodos de uma Activity em um Fragmento

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Estou tentando usar alguns métodos de uma Activity em um Fragmento, porem não estou conseguindo, alguém sabe me dizer se é possível?

```
public class updateMarker extends Activity {
    TextView uid;

    //URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "http://t4web.hospedagemdesites.ws/alarme/update.php";

    //JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_USER = "markers";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";


    JSONArray markers = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.teste);


        new JSONParse().execute();
    }

    public class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uid);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(updateMarker.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Carregando..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                // Getting JSON Array
                markers = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
                JSONObject c = markers.getJSONObject(0);

                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);


                //Set JSON Data in TextView
                uid.setText(id);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Pretendo usar todos os métodos dessa classe nesse Fragmento:

```
public class UpdatesFragment extends Fragment {


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.updates_layout, null);
    }
}
```

Alguém sabe me informar se é possível? Se sim, como?

Comment: Porque é que a classe *updateMarker extends Activity*?

Comment: A classe *updateMarker* só tem o método *onCreate*, quando diz "Pretendo usar todos os métodos" está a referir-se apenas em usar a *AsyncTask*?

Comment: @ramaral Estou me referindo ao onCreate e o AsyncTask

Comment: @ramaral sabe me dizer se consigo instanciar um AsyncTask ? Preciso executar ele em outra classe, é possível ?

Comment: O meu comentário anterior ia no sentido de lhe dar uma resposta onde explicaria como utilizar o *AsyncTask* em qualquer outra classe mas, em face do que você disse, não era isso que queria.

Comment: @ramaral na verdade, consegui transformar a minha Activity em um Fragmento, mas quero usar o mesmo AsyncTask em outras classes, pode me auxiliar ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33105/discussion-between-tharley-carvalho-and-ramaral).

Answer (score 2):

Se o que quer é puder utilizar a *AsyncTask* em qualquer classe declare-a em um arquivo à parte e defina um construtor que receba um *context* e um *listener* para onde será passado o resultado.

```
public class MyParser extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    //Interface que o Listener deve implementar
    public interface OnResultListener {
        void onResult(String id);
    }

    //JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_USER = "markers";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private Context context;
    private onResultListener listener;

    public MyParser(Context context, OnResultListener listener){

        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Carregando..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        String url = args[0];
        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            // Getting JSON Array
            JSONArray markers = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
            JSONObject c = markers.getJSONObject(0);

            // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);


            //Chama o callback com o id
            if(listener != null){
                listener.onResult(id);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Para utilizar:

```
MyParser parser = new MyParser(context, new MyParser.OnResultListener() {

    @Override
    public void onResult(String id) {

        //Utilize o id como entender.
    }
});

parser.execute("http://t4web.hospedagemdesites.ws/alarme/update.php");
```

Comment: Infelizmente não me atende. Vamos lá, tenho uma classe que com marcadores no mapa, e cada marcação ele atualiza a anterior com o         new RetrieveTask().execute(); ! Quero que ao atualizar os marcadores, atualizar a quantidade de marcação com AsyncTask que postei anteriormente.

Comment: O que é que isso tem haver com aquilo que você pediu? Não faço ideia do que seja essa *RetrieveTask*. Faça nova pergunta tendo em conta que não conhecemos o seu código e não conseguimos ler seu pensamento. :)

Answer (score 1):

Para isto, você deve fazer um `cast` em `getActivity()`

```
 UpdateMarker updateMarker = ((UpdateMarker)getActivity());
```

Isto irá funcionar apenas se realmente a `UpdateMarker` for a `Activity` da `Fragment`

Comment: Thiago, sabe me dizer se consigo instanciar um AsyncTask ? Preciso executar ele em outra classe, é possível ?

Comment: Sim, para isso deixe a estática. Para instanciar use **new  UpdateMarker.JSONParse();**

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde !

Você pode instanciar uma async task sim !
Primeiro você utiliza um construtor para instanciar:

`JSONParse parse = new JSONParse ();`

Depois você executa a asynctask com os parâmetros que você declarou para serem passados:

`parse.execute(var);`

Comment: Tentei dessa forma porem ele não reconhece minha classe, então tentei         UpdatesFragment.JSONParse parse = new UpdatesFragment.JSONParse(); ! Mas também não deu certo, logs: Error:(100, 43) error: an enclosing instance that contains UpdatesFragment.JSONParse is required

Comment: A classe está num arquivo separado ? Se sim, importe a mesma e veja se da certo.

Comment: Ele esta em outra classe, mesmo importando ele não reconhece.

Comment: Como a classe esta estendendo uma activity, tenta usar um intent: Intent update = new Intent(this,updateMarker.class);
            startActivity(update);